# Any reason not to buy bitcoins using a bank card?

Tags: exchanges

If I'm new to bitcoin and I want to buy coins at an exchange like mtgox solely for the purpose of seeing currency value increase and selling at a profit, is there any good for reason for me to not simply buy bitcoins by entering my visa number on mtgox in the same way I buy anything else online? As opposed to say meeting someone in person and giving them cash in exchange for bitcoins?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. I strongly doubt Mt. Gox accepts CC funding, so you can't do that because they don't allow you to.

Answer (score 0):

That is done to prevent fraud (in other words, people could "pay" with CC, get their bitcoins, and then dispute the transaction).

Answer (score -1):

Well, an obvious reason would be if you were concerned about anonymity and not leaving an audit trail, in order to conceal your funds from tax authorities, for example.